# How to use UnexpectedValueException and LogicException outside of controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

So I have an Helper function that validate `JWT token` every time it called and for the `catch` it uses `UnexpectedValueException` and `LogicException`. I already use the namespace for that Exception but it still not working

the helper.php is located inside of `app` folder

here is my Helper :

```
 <?php

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\Key;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\LogicException as LogicException;
use App\Http\Controllers\UnexpectedValueException as UnexpectedValueException;
use App\Http\Controllers;
// use UnexpectedValueException;


if(!function_exists('validateJWT')){
    function validateJWT($token){
        //v Checking the JWT token
        // $jwt = $_COOKIE['userData'];
        try{
            JWT::decode($token,new Key(env('JWT_SECRET'),'HS256'));

        }catch(LogicException | UnexpectedValueException $e){
            // dd($e->getMessage());

            setcookie('userData', null);
            Auth::guard('web')->logout();
            session()->invalidate();
            session()->regenerateToken();

            return redirect()->to('/');
        }
        //v ////////////////////////////
    }
}
```

it supposed to redirect it to home with logout state when the token is modified or expired but the laravel not using the `Exception` catch and proceed displaying dev trace.
[image: exception]

Comment: The exception being thrown is `SignatureInvalidException`, which you're not catching...

Comment: Also, don't use `env()` in Controllers. If you ever run `php artisan config:cache`, then `env()` will return `null`. You'd need to move `JWT_TOKEN` to a file in your `config` folder, like `app.php`, `'jwt_token' => env('JWT_TOKEN')`, and load it via `config('app.jwt_token')` (or similar)

Comment: based on [jwt/firebase docs](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) all the exception is extended from `UnexpectedValueException` . But anyway I use the direct `SignatureInvalidException` and it success, but it wont redirect me to home page ('/')

Comment: thankyou for the advice I'll move the secret key to the config

Comment: Ah ok, so your import then is incorrect (or you don't need to import it at all). Try `catch (\UnexpectedValueException $e)` like how Firebase does it: https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/main/src/SignatureInvalidException.php#L5, or leave it as an explicit catch of `SignatureInvalidException`; either should work.

Comment: ahhhh thats it thankyou it works!, I'll use the `catch(\LogicException | \UnexpectedValueException  $e)` so it would be much cleaner

for the redirecting I can just returns it with `boolean` and check it whenever the function is called

Comment: Excellent! Yeah, Laravel namespaces can sometimes muck with native PHP functions/classes, but as long as you prefix em with a forward slash, it should work. I'd have expected that `use LogicException;` and `use UnexpectedValueException;` would allow you to simply do `catch(LogicException | UnexpectedValueException $e)`, but again, finicky. Glad you got it working!

Comment: yeah, I'm tried to use the `use LogicException;` and `use UnexpectedValueException;` and it's not working I thought it was extended from controller function or something. 
Thankyou for the answer! :)

Comment: Hmm... Very odd; if I do `use LogicException;`, and a simple test function `try { throw new LogicException('Testing'); } catch (LogicException $ex) { dd('Caught a \`LogicException\`: ' .$ex->getMessage()); }`, I see `"Caught a \`LogicException\`: Testing"` logged successfully in my code... I wonder why that doesn't work for your case  Only real difference is code cleanliness, so not a huge issue, but still, curious.

Comment: when I use it like that, laravel would turns this error at the top of the page `Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'UnexpectedValueException' has no effect in C:\laragon\www\AquaFoliage\app\helper.php on line 7`

Comment: Yeah, and I've definitely seen that error (warning) before, and expected it to be displayed here, but my code just worked. Maybe it's a PHP version thing, but I honestly don't know ‍♂️

Comment: yea that's everything is working but that warning is looks annoying to look at lmao